# How to use $sql_tbl[] when create a new table in smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, database

I have created a new table in database (mysql, table name `zip_backup_management`). I want to use `$sql_tbl[zip_backup_management]` in a php page. But in sql query it can't add the table name. I am using this query in smarty

```
(SELECT * FROM $sql_tbl[zip_backup_management] WHERE cd_nr <> 0 ORDER BY cd_nr) UNION (SELECT * FROM $sql_tbl[zip_management] WHERE cd_nr = 0)
```

Comment: what does $sql_tbl[zip_backup_management] contain?

Comment: Is there any error??? Have you executed the query?? Is there any value getting for $sql_tbl[zip_backup_management] in the query??

Comment: $sql_tbl is used to automatically add  xcart_ in front of table name.

Comment: Why (and how) are you using Smarty to generate or run SQL? Is this some other system called Smarty rather than the template engine?

Answer (score 0):

Use `assign` key word in tpl page.

```
{assign var=zip_management value=$sql_tbl[zip_management]}
```

Then execute query like this,

```
{(SELECT * FROM $zip_management WHERE cd_nr <> 0 ORDER BY cd_nr) UNION (SELECT * FROM $zip_management WHERE cd_nr = 0)}
```